# How can I fully use all my extensions from vscode local machine into vscode.dev (code server)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm completely new to using vscode code-server.

The extensions I'm trying to use is **"vscode-pdf"** which allows vscode to read encoded pdf files, since I wanted to have both the code and pdf window open simultaneously on my ipad. I did turn on **"Setting Sync"** but only this extension not appearing on my remote browser, any idea please?

I did try to google and read the official guidelines but I couldn't find any discussion on the matter.